# Remove duplicate dict based on field values

Tags: python

Given the following list of dicts, I want to remove duplicates where all fields are identical *except for* the id field.

```
old_data = [
{"id":"01","name":"harry","age":21},
{"id":"02","name":"barry","age":32},
{"id":"03","name":"harry","age":44},
{"id":"04","name":"harry","age":21},
{"id":"05","name":"larry","age":66}
]
```

To produce the following:

```
new_data = [
{"id":"01","name":"harry","age":21},
{"id":"02","name":"barry","age":32},
{"id":"03","name":"harry","age":44},
{"id":"05","name":"larry","age":66}
]
```

My current code only works for cases where all fields of the dictionary are identical:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
for x in old_data:
 if x not in new_d:
   new_data.append(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Build a dict with the significant part of the dict as the key, then turn the values back into a list:

```
>>> old_data = [
... {"id":"01","name":"harry","age":21},
... {"id":"02","name":"barry","age":32},
... {"id":"03","name":"harry","age":44},
... {"id":"04","name":"harry","age":21},
... {"id":"05","name":"larry","age":66}
... 
>>> sorted({(d["name"], d["age"]): d for d in reversed(old_data)}.values(), key=lambda d: d["id"])
[{'id': '01', 'name': 'harry', 'age': 21}, {'id': '02', 'name': 'barry', 'age': 32}, {'id': '03', 'name': 'harry', 'age': 44}, {'id': '05', 'name': 'larry', 'age': 66}]
```

If you don't care about which specific ids you keep or how they're sorted, it's simpler:

```
>>> list({(d["name"], d["age"]): d for d in old_data}.values())
[{'id': '04', 'name': 'harry', 'age': 21}, {'id': '02', 'name': 'barry', 'age': 32}, {'id': '03', 'name': 'harry', 'age': 44}, {'id': '05', 'name': 'larry', 'age': 66}]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:  I ignore id in my comparison

```
def remove_duplicate(old_data):
    new_data = []
    for i in old_data:
        found=False
        for j in new_data:
            if (j['name']==i['name']) & (j['age']==i['age']):
                found=True
                break;
        if found==False:
            new_data.append(i)
    return new_data

old_data = [
{"id":"01","name":"harry","age":21},
{"id":"02","name":"barry","age":32},
{"id":"03","name":"harry","age":44},
{"id":"04","name":"harry","age":21},
{"id":"05","name":"larry","age":66}
]

print(remove_duplicate(old_data))
```

output:

```
[{'id': '01', 'name': 'harry', 'age': 21}, {'id': '02', 'name': 'barry', 'age': 32}, {'id': '03', 'name': 'harry', 'age': 44}, {'id': '05', 'name': 'larry', 'age': 66}]
```

Answer (score 0):

a straight forward solution could be just to keep track of dicts in list.

```
old_data = [
    {"id":"01","name":"harry","age":21},
    {"id":"02","name":"barry","age":32},
    {"id":"03","name":"harry","age":44},
    {"id":"04","name":"harry","age":21},
    {"id":"05","name":"larry","age":66}
]

track_list = []
new_data = []
for obj in old_data:
    if [obj['name'], obj['age']] in  track_list:
        continue
    else:
        track_list.append([obj['name'], obj['age']])
        new_data.append(obj)
        
print(new_data)
```

output

```
[{'id': '01', 'name': 'harry', 'age': 21}, {'id': '02', 'name': 'barry', 'age': 32}, {'id': '03', 'name': 'harry', 'age': 44}, {'id': '05', 'name': 'larry', 'age': 66}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Only hardcoding `'id'`, not the other keys:

```
tmp = {}
for d in old_data:
    k = frozenset(d.items() - {('id', d['id'])})
    tmp.setdefault(k, d)
new_data = list(tmp.values())
```